# Flutter - Automatically start application on Firebase FCM Notification Received

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm developing an application, related to Child Security, in Flutter.

A parent can request the child's application to send an **Image** or a **15 seconds Audio**.

**FCM** is implemented and perfectly working fine **when the application is running or in the background**. When a notification received on Child's mobile application, the application moves to the relevant screen and performs the task.

But when the application is closed/terminated, it's not working. The notification is received, but the application doesn't start automatically. **I have to click the notification, which I don't want to.**

Can I achieve this, in Flutter? Something like **WhatsApp or Facebook Messenger** call feature?

What I have tried so far is, calling the `main` function on a notification received or `runApp`, but got no success.

```
void _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) {
    main();
    <------- and ------>
    runApp(MaterialApp(home: ChildDashboard()));
}

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
  runApp(MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: CustomSplash(
        imagePath: 'assets/images/logo.png',
        backGroundColor: Colors.pink[50],
        animationEffect: 'zoom-in',
        logoSize: 1000,
        home: sendToRelevantScreen(),
        duration: 2500,
        type: CustomSplashType.StaticDuration,
    ),
 ));
}
```

Comment: Interesting. I actually also need to figure this out. Dont have a solution yet.

Comment: @mogren3000 I also didn't get any solution yet.

Comment: I guess that this could be possible if the application could use system specific permissions, but that not allowed in newer versions of android.

Comment: Any progress now?

Comment: No, I didn't get any solution.